# How to run a Jenkins job on multiple virtual servers?

Tags: jenkins, devops

I have installed Jenkins on a server ,by default the job will run on that server only .My requirement is from my Jenkins how I can run the the same job on to multiple server ?How it will ssh to other servers ? I am new to Jenkins,Please help .Basically my aim is to deploy a application on to multiple servers .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use any of the configuration management tool like ansible, chef or capistrano as jenkins jobs so that they can do your work with jenkins. You can mention the number of servers under the capistrano cookbook and whenever you will build the job it will run your task on all servers.

There is also a tool like pssh(parallel ssh), In case you want to use ssh.

Answer (score 4):

**Ansible** is the best way for this.
[Ansible :](https://networklore.com/ansible/)

Install [Ansible](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-ansible-on-centos-7) in the same server where Jenkins get installed.

Configure the multiple servers details in the host file under a single name.

Mention the jobs in [Ansible-playbook](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html) which will get executed in all the mentioned servers.

> internal process: it will run the job in the multiple servers by ssh
>   in to it

or

use shell script in the Jenkins installed server and use shell command along with ssh username@ip "#cmd" //mulitple server ip

Comment: for git pull we do the setup in Jenkins,if from the "execute shell" I will try to execute ssh username@ip and then the rest commands for multiple servers it will be lengthy . Is there any plugin in Jenkins to ssh to multiple servers ? I am learning Chef ,in case of Ansible can I use Chef ?

Comment: Yes, shell scripting will be lengthy.. you should go with Ansible/Chef/Puppet (Software Configuration Management tool). Compare to Chef/puppet  Ansible is the best and easy one(easy to understand,document,easy to implement, latest one). while others(chef/puppet) were client-server method but Ansible is not which is the great advantage of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the master-slave Concept. Install jenkins slave in all other machines, i.e in your case the other application servers. You can find more about Jenkins master slave concept from [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines+on+Windows).

You can then use the same job to run on other application servers.

Comment: Thank you this really helped ,now I am able to deploy the same application on to multiple servers by adding a slave .

Answer (score 0):

I think by using single job with post build steps you can deploy on multiple servers.

Let me know in case if any corrections

Comment: how Jenkins will ssh to other server to run the job in other server .?

Answer (score 0):

Using Master-Slave Concept, You can add Jenkins slave agent on multiple slave nodes, so you can deploy on them.

You can deploy in two ways, Either using Jenkins node pipeline syntax, or using Ansible-Playbook through the Building Script:

First Way would be as follows in the Jenkinsfile:

```
node('node1') {
   // Building Stages on node 1
}

node('node2') {
   // Building Stages node 2
}
```

Second Way would be as follow in Jenkinsfile:

```
node('master_node'){
// master node has the ansible-playbook

ansiblePlaybook credentialsId: 'ansible_ssh_user', inventory: 'path_to_inventory_file', playbook: 'path_to_playbook', sudo: true, sudoUser: 'sudo_user_name'

}
```

This way requires to install Ansible-plugin on the Jenkins Master Node.
and you can put all the nodes you want in the Inventory file.

The main difference between the two ways besides to Idempotence, The First way will provide a sequential execution, while the Second way will provide a parallel execution using Ansible.