# Automate publishing .NET Core App to multiple subdomains

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2019, webdeploy

I have a .NET Core application used by many clients. Each client has its own subdomain. Each client has its own database. All databases are identical. Different data, same schema. The subdomains and database names look something like this.

```
client1.myapp.com     Client1Db
client2.myapp.com     Client2Db
client3.myapp.com     Client3Db
```

I use Visual Studio Web Deploy to publish. For each client, I have publishing-settings.

Each set of publishing-settings specifies the proper subdomain, the database name for that subdomain, and the Entity Framework Migration Info for the subdomain. (See images below)

I end up with a list of .pubxml files in my VisualStudioSolution\Properties\PublishProfiles folder that looks kind of like this...

```
client1.myapp.com.pubxml
client1.myapp.com.pubxml.user
client2.myapp.com.pubxml
client2.myapp.com.pubxml.user
client3.myapp.com.pubxml
client3.myapp.com.pubxml.user
```

It was not a big deal to publish these individually when I only had a few subdomains to publish, but now I'm getting enough clients that it is becoming a pain.

Can someone recommend a way to automate this process? I'm not even sure where to start. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use a DevOps pipeline in which you can use, for example "Jenkins X" and deploy a single app to multiple servers.

You can start with: [Jenkins jobs in multiple servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490654/how-to-run-a-jenkins-job-on-multiple-virtual-servers)

There is others CD (continuous delivery) platforms and services, but this question have better place in [devops.stackexchange](https://devops.stackexchange.com/)